# Reverse from POS tagging to sentence using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, pos-tagger

I have pos_token dataset and I want to transform them to be a sentence again using pandas

| pos_token | sentence |
| --- | --- |
| [(No, DT), (you, PRP), (lying, VBG)] | No you lying |

Comment: data in pos_token is list or string as list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if pos_token is a list values then try this;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"pos_token":[[("No", "DT"), ("you", "PRP"), ("lying", "VBG")]]})

df["sentence"] = df["pos_token"].apply(lambda x: " ".join([i[0] for i in x]))

#  output
                              pos_token      sentence
0  [(No, DT), (you, PRP), (lying, VBG)]  No you lying
```

Comment: Glad to Help @ ... Drop a like & accept the best answer that works for your problem statement... To grow & motivate community... Happy Coding :)